# Json to list of objects with marshmellow Python

Tags: python, json, flask, serialization, marshmallow

I have json with data about my object
I created schema for serialize it into list of objects, but it isn't work

Schema:

```
from marshmellow import fields, Schema

class ContactSchema(Schema):
    first_name = fields.String(attribute="ftNm")
    last_name = fields.String(attribute="ltNm")
    phone = fields.Integer(attribute="pn")
```

Model:

```
class Contact:
    id: int
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    phone: str
```

And i have a function to convert (but is not working)

```
def json_to_list():
    json = [{'ftNm': 'Name1', 'ltNm': 'Surname1', 'pn': 343434},
            {'ftNm': 'Name2', 'ltNm': 'Surname2', 'pn': 141414}, 
            {'ftNm': 'Name3', 'ltNm': 'Surname3', 'pn': 656565}]

    schema = ContactSchema()
    result = schema.dump(json)
```

I will appreciate if someone help me with function to convert json to list of objects

Comment: `but is not working` – what's the error?

Comment: there is just logic error, I just need the right function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your intentions are. However, serialization and deserialization are possible in the following ways.

Serialization and deserialization with renaming of the attributes specified by the variable names.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
    
class ContactSchema(Schema):
    first_name = fields.Str(attribute="ftNm", data_key="ftNm")
    last_name = fields.Str(attribute="ltNm", data_key="ltNm")
    phone = fields.Integer(attribute="pn", data_key="pn")

# serialization to json
def from_list():
    data = [
        {'ftNm': 'Name1', 'ltNm': 'Surname1', 'pn': 343434},
        {'ftNm': 'Name2', 'ltNm': 'Surname2', 'pn': 141414},
        {'ftNm': 'Name3', 'ltNm': 'Surname3', 'pn': 656565}
    ]
    schema = ContactSchema(many=True)
    return schema.dump(data)

# deserialization from json
def to_list():
    json = [
        {'ftNm': 'Name1', 'ltNm': 'Surname1', 'pn': 343434},
        {'ftNm': 'Name2', 'ltNm': 'Surname2', 'pn': 141414},
        {'ftNm': 'Name3', 'ltNm': 'Surname3', 'pn': 656565}
    ]
    schema = ContactSchema(many=True)
    return schema.load(json)
```

Deserialization without renaming of the attributes specified by the variable names.

```
class ContactSchema(Schema):
    first_name = fields.Str(attribute="ftNm")
    last_name = fields.Str(attribute="ltNm")
    phone = fields.Integer(attribute="pn")

# deserialization from json
def to_list():
    json = [
        {'first_name': 'Name1', 'last_name': 'Surname1', 'phone': 343434},
        {'first_name': 'Name2', 'last_name': 'Surname2', 'phone': 141414},
        {'first_name': 'Name3', 'last_name': 'Surname3', 'phone': 656565}
    ]
    schema = ContactSchema(many=True)
    return schema.load(json)
```

The direction of the conversion may not be indicated correctly.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Contact:
    # id: int
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    phone: str

class ContactSchema(Schema):
    first_name = fields.Str(data_key="ftNm")
    last_name = fields.Str(data_key="ltNm")
    phone = fields.Integer(data_key="pn")

    @post_load
    def make_user(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Contact(**data)

# deserialization from json
def to_list():
    json = [
        {'ftNm': 'Name1', 'ltNm': 'Surname1', 'pn': 343434},
        {'ftNm': 'Name2', 'ltNm': 'Surname2', 'pn': 141414},
        {'ftNm': 'Name3', 'ltNm': 'Surname3', 'pn': 656565}
    ]
    schema = ContactSchema(many=True)
    return schema.load(json)
```

To serialize and deserialize a database model, I recommend [flask-marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know is it normally, but I just created a simple function and deserialize through the loop

```
    def create(self, json: dict):
        key = Key()
        key.id = json.get("id")
        key.key_number = json.get("num")
        key.hash = json.get("hash")

        return key
```

Comment: Marschmallow has the advantage of a number of predefined fields and the possibility to validate them. See also the combination of marshmalllow and webargs. Especially as your project gets bigger it might help you. I am a friend of small, simple solutions and would be happy for you if your approach meets the expectation.